# Intersection between a line and an n-dimensional parallelotope

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-polytopes

Suppose that I have a line in an $n$-dimensional space described by
$$ X=A+Bk, \quad \quad X,A,B \in \mathbb{R}^n, k \in \mathbb{R} $$
here $A$ is known and I want to find all the possible vectors $B$ such that this line has one and only one intersection with the set $S$ described by: 
$$S=\{ X \in \mathbb{R}^n \: | \: 0 \le X \le W\} $$ where $W \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$ and the inequalities are to be intended component-wise.

Is there any closed-form formula for such vectors $B$?

Comment: I would not expect a closed form formula. Are you interested in a general procedure to find this set?

Answer (score -1):

Line-Plane Intersection. In 3D, a line L is either parallel to a plane P or intersects it in a single point. ... We first check if L is parallel to P by testing if , which means that the line direction vector u is perpendicular to the plane normal n.

Comment: Yes but since I want to find all vectors $B$ such that there is just one intersection, that can happen if and only if the line passes through either a vertex or an edge of my parallelotope, isn't that right?